# Is GitHub's view-branch feature stateless, and, if so, how might it be implemented?

Tags: git, github

In a browser, you can go to GitHub and change the branch from, e.g., `master` to a feature branch, and in GitHub's web app [you now see](https://github.com/git/git/tree/next) the filesystem from the perspective of the topic branch.  When you do this in a local Git repo, you're mutating the state of the repo, changing the contents of the filesystem in the process and switching the current branch.  And sometimes this process can take several seconds. By contrast, I wouldn't be surprised if GitHub's implementation is stateless, and there is no repo on GitHub's server that is being checked out and updated in this way.  If the implementation is stateless, how might they be doing that?

In a stateless implementation, would computing the view in a directory under the repo be expensive enough to *require* caching of the traversal of the Git object graph?  Or is the computing of the directory contents fast enough to be possible to redo with every page load, even if caching is a nice convenience to make page loads even faster?

(I ask all this because I'm hoping to do something similar with an app I'm working on, but not involving Git.)

Comment: "*…see the filesystem from the perspective of the topic branch. When you do this in a local Git repo, you're mutating the state of the repo, changing the contents of the filesystem in the process and switching the current branch…*" Not at all. You can see the history of a topic branch using `git log topic_branch_name` without switching to it.

Comment: @phd yes, this is true.  Are `git log` and related commands an adequate basis for the GitHub file view?  And are they always fast, in contrast, for example, to checking out a branch locally, which can sometimes be slow?

Comment: GitHub doesn't use command line programs, especially porcelaine. Github uses `libgit` that is the low-level code which is the basis for plumbing command. In the command line the plumbing command to list commits is [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list).

Comment: Does the structure of the Git object graph guarantee that functions from `libgit` used to derive a file view will always be fast?  Or are there corner cases where these function calls will take a while?  From experience using read-only Git commands, I would guess that they're always fast for displaying a file view on a branch.  But I didn't want to assume that when `git checkout` is slow, this was always due to unpacking stuff into the filesystem.

Comment: "*Does the structure of the Git object graph guarantee that functions from libgit used to derive a file view will always be fast?*" No idea. "*…when git checkout is slow, this was always due to unpacking stuff into the filesystem.*" Unpacking, filesystem access, hooks.

Comment: Note that there isn't any real "computation" involved in producing a file view like this; you're just (a) looking up a commit and then (b) recursively reading tree objects from that commit object. You don't have to compute differences, traverse the tree to find anything other than the target commit, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a browser, you can go to GitHub and change the branch from, e.g., master to a feature branch ...

Note that this does save some state.  It saves it in your browser, though.

> and in GitHub's web app you now see the filesystem from the perspective of the topic branch.

That's because the "path" you supply to GitHub now tells it to pick the topic-branch revision.

> When you do this in a local Git repo, you're mutating the state of the repo, changing the contents of the filesystem in the process and switching the current branch.

That's true for `git checkout` or `git switch`: you tell Git to change the stored state (in `HEAD`), and to update Git's index (stored state inside Git) and your working tree (stored state outside Git).  But you don't need to use those two commands.

> And sometimes this process can take several seconds.

Or more, depending on many things: with particularly large repos (several gigabytes) with large working trees (a million or more files) and correspondingly large index files, there may be a lot of index entries to update, and a lot of working tree files to replace.

> By contrast, I wouldn't be surprised if GitHub's implementation is stateless, and there is no repo on GitHub's server that is being checked out and updated in this way. If the implementation is stateless, how might they be doing that?

A *commit hash ID* specifies a revision.  If you have the repository—the database of objects—looking up the commit from the commit hash ID is basically O(1), with numerous caveats.  See the bullet point section below.

A *branch or tag name* specifies a name in a name-to-hash-ID table.  If you have the table in a suitable form, looking up a commit hash ID (branch names and some tag names) or annotated-tag-object hash ID (some tag names) is also basically O(1).  Traditional Git storage uses a very crappy kind of database for these, though, where looking up the hash ID is O(n) in the number of stored names.  (Whether and when GitHub use a better database, I don't know.)

Once you have the hash ID from a branch or tag name, you can look up the object—annotated tag object, or commit object—in O(1) as above, and if it is an annotated tag object, you can look up its target in O(1) as well, since the target is given by hash ID.  (However, the target of an annotated tag can be another annotated tag: in this case, finding the final hash ID is O(n) in the number of annotated tag objects traversed.)

Having found a commit hash ID, it is an O(n) job to turn a string style pathname into a blob hash ID (or an error indicating that this path does not appear in this commit).  One must break up the string into components—separated by forward slashes—and use the `tree` hash ID stored in the commit to find the first component, then use each sub-tree hash ID for each subsequent component, until reaching the final component, which should specify a tree or blob object or, for submodules, a gitlink.  A gitlink terminates the search notionally since it is presumed to be a commit hash ID in some other repository.  A tree object indicates that this is a "directory" full of more component names; a blob object ID indicates that you have found the symlink target (`mode 120000`) or file content (file modes `100644` or `100755`, or the other compatibility modes starting with `100` and having three more octal digits—these should not occur in new repositories, but existing, pre-Git-1.5.5 repositories have them).

Here's where the O(1) search from hash IDs goes a bit wonky:

- Objects, in a Git repository, are stored either *loose* or *packed*.
- A loose object is in `.git/objects/ab/cdef...` where the `ab` part is the first two hexadecimal digits and the `cdef...` part is the rest.  If this loose object exists, you open, read, and decompress it and you have the object data, including the object header, which is an ASCII text string consisting of the object type (`commit`, `tag`, `tree`, or `blob`) followed by a space (0x20) followed by the decimalized representation of the object's size in bytes followed by a NUL byte (0x00) followed by the object data.  Tree objects are stored as binary data;<sup>1</sup> the rest are stored as text, or are the blob object data for a `blob` object.
- A *packed* object is stored in a *pack file*.  A pack file generally has an *index*, which allows for fast location of the packed object (or determination that it does not exist), and pack headers that allow unpacking of the packed object.  However, the packed object is now optionally [delta-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) against other objects within the same pack.  This requires expanding out those objects (or parts of them).  These objects can also be delta-encoded, up to some maximum chain length.  Decoding a heavily packed object can therefore take a lot more work than the O(1) it takes to find the existence of the object via the index.

All of this assumes that you have direct access to the Git object database.  It also either requires using a code library, or duplicating the functionality of Git, or running `git cat-file -p` or similar.  Spawning processes is the easiest way to tackle this portably (it automatically works with new Git versions), but efficiency might suffer a bit.  Consider using `git rev-parse` and `git cat-file --batch-check` as cleverly as you can here.

---

<sup>1</sup>This was, I claim, a mistake.  The part that is truly binary is the hash ID and it would have been nice to have room to store both SHA-1 and SHA-256 IDs here when appropriate.  That's impossible without a change to the tree object format.  As mistakes go, though, it's pretty minor.